# What are the differences between the usage of 'it' and 'they'?

Tags: word-meaning, pronouns, relative-pronouns, singular-they

I need to understand the following with respect to correct grammar not everyday usage:
1. The number to the antecedent that both pronouns can refer to (Singular/Plural)
2. Can the pronouns refer to living and non-living creatures both?
3. Any other rules that distinguish the two.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92153/discussion-on-question-by-ayushi-grover-what-are-the-differences-between-the-usa).

Answer (score 10):

*It* is always singular, and hardly ever used of humans (some people refer to a baby whose sex they don't know as "it", but others find that offensive). It is often used of animals, but many people use "he" or "she" if they know the sex of the animal.

*They* is plural, and may refer to anything: people, animals, inanimate objects. Many people (including  me) also use it in the singular to refer to a person when they don't know the person's gender, or are referring to an unspecified person who might be of any gender. Some people object to this use, but it has been around for centuries.

I don't remember ever having heard singular "they" used of an animal - most people would use "it" in such cases. As far as I know, singular "they" is never used for inanimate objects.

Comment: Oh, I've heard it used for an animal - some people object to thinking about them as less than human, somehow.

Comment: I use "they" for animals exclusively. At least for mammals, birds, and reptiles; I tend to lean towards "it" for insects. The exact line varies from person to person, some only using they for humans and some using it for humans and pets, others for all animate things, etc. Also of note is that singular they can be used for a _specific_ nonbinary person as well, so it doesn't have to be an unspecified person or a person of unknown gender.